# Template doest not exist at /

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django. I made a folder named templates in my project and `Home.html` inside it. After running the server, I am getting error `TemplateDoesNotExist`, as seen in following screenshot:

[image: the error image]

My `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'Home.html'
```

My `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
# from . import views
from .views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.IndexView, name='IndexView')
    path("", HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

From my `settings.py`:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also I have attached the screenshot of the error. Please help me. This is my first project of Django.

Comment: just create a **Home.html** file in `theblog` directory andadd html code you want

Comment: I have done this. Still nothing happened, getting same error

Comment: main_project/theblog/templates/home.html correct template  name case

Comment: it showing error for post_list.html also create file